# Map an object to an object with a sub list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

I have a class:

```
public class LearnerEvent
{
    public string SubjectField { get; set; }

    public string GradeField { get; set; }

    public DateTime AchievementAwardDateField { get; set; }

    public string QualificationTypeField { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to map this to a DTO:

```
public class LearnerEventDto
{
    public List<LearnerEventInfoDto> LearnerEventInfo { get; set; }

    public string QualificationTypeField { get; set; }
}
```

which has a sub-dto:

```
public class LearnerEventInfoDto
{
    public string SubjectField { get; set; }

    public string GradeField { get; set; }

    public DateTime AchievementAwardDateField { get; set; }
}
```

The purpose is so I can display the objects in groups ie. grouping by award type.

I know I probably have to write a custom mapper (using automapper) but I'm just not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping you want would mean that every InfoDTO object in that list would have to have the same QualificationType, which means that you've already filtered your LearnerEvents to a specific type. There shouldn't be any need to write the QualificationType into a "DTO list".

I'm guessing that you're working with a DTO because you don't want to distribute the LearnerEvent class or because you want to filter certain information which you haven't shown in your example, so what I would do is creating the LearnerEventDTOs with the fields from the LearnerEvent you want to transmit, put them in a List and send them to wherever you want.

The other side can determine the QualificationType by looking it up on any elemen and the items are supposed to have the same QualificationType anyway.

Comment: I originally had it the way you are suggesting but my manager said he wants all the sorting to be done before it gets back to the front end.

Comment: by sorting I mean grouping by Qualification

Comment: But they are grouped already.

If you write the QualificationType into the ListDTO, then any ListItemDTO in that ListDTO must have the that exact QualficiationType or otherwise your contract is invalid.

Therefore, you have already grouped your Events.